# Spring boot: H2 test database don't recognize "serial4"

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2

I'm using h2 as in memory in order to test a spring repository class.
But when h2 try to create the table return:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "SERIAL4";

The ddl of the table show that the id column is a serial4 datatype.

***id serial4 NOT NULL***

But h2 don't recognize that.
The origina table is under postgresql.

There is any type of solution?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've updated the applications.yaml of test enviroment, but the result is the same. Here's the updated yaml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test_name
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 500
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;MODE=POSTGRESQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_schema\;
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
```

Comment: Well not use H2 but the actual database you are using for your system? Looks like you are using H2 but still have JPA configured (or whatever you use) to use the dialect for your production type database.

Comment: I didn't catch that, sorry, i paste my application-test.yaml: jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 500
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;MODE=POSTGRESQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_schema\;

Comment: Don't add additional code as comments as that is totally unreadable. You are using H2, but your database in prod is Postgres. You have configured hibernate as such with the dialect...

Comment: Sorry. However i've changed the jpa.database-platform from org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect to org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect but i still receive the same error

Comment: If you really changed it I doubt you get the same error. So either you didn't change it  or it isn't available yet. Or you have another conflicting / influencing properties file somewhere .

Comment: I'm going to paste my application.yaml file:

Comment: ```spring:
  application:
    name: test_name
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 500
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;MODE=POSTGRESQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_schema\;
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO```

Comment: Please don't add additional code as comments as that is unreadable (as mentioned before). Edit your question instead.